# volume off does not work in html5 video ipad 2

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, html5-video

volume off does not work in html5 video ipad 2.

```
player = document.getElementById(element_id);
if (player.muted){
    player.muted = false;
    player.volume = 1;
    //player.volume(1);
}else{
    player.muted = true;
    player.volume = 0;
    //player.volume(0);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I'm afraid iOS does not allow changing the volume with Javascript. From Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1) (emphasis is mine):

> On the desktop, you can set and read the volume property of an  or  element. This allows you to set the element’s audio volume relative to the computer’s current volume setting. A value of 1 plays sound at the normal level. A value of 0 silences the audio. Values between 0 and 1 attenuate the audio.
>
> This volume adjustment can be useful, because it allows the user to mute a game, for example, while still listening to music on the computer.
>
> **On iOS devices, the audio level is always under the user’s physical control. The volume property is not settable in JavaScript. Reading the volume property always returns 1.**

There is no mention of the `muted` property, but experimenting shows that it can't be changed either:
http://jsbin.com/anikab/1/

Answer (score -2):

I've been able to achieve something like this by doing the following:

- To mute, remove the entire  element. Easily done if you're using jquery.

  $('#audio-elem').remove();
- To unmute, simply add it back in!

  $('body').append('');

I did find two issues with this method though:

- The iPad doesn't cache audio so it needs to reload it when added back in. That means there will be a delay before the audio starts playing again.
- The audio will play from the start, that is 00:00, when loaded back in.

Hope it helps!

Comment: To whoever down voted this and to all other down voters out there, please give a reason when doing so so that we know why our solution isn't perfect. It would help the solution writers as well as the readers to know what the problem is. For example, this work around gave me the result I wanted but it's not perfect. I'd like to know what I could do to make it better. Thanks!

Comment: Would venture that this isn't a viable solution for most people facing the problem, because "muting" video tends to mean that while the video continues playing, the audio doesn't. Unless I'm missing something, your solution is akin to just turning off a TV, which technically DOES kill the sound, but isn't exactly "muting".

Comment: Ah yes, that is true. This won't work for video. In my case I was using this method to "mute" a background sound track. :)